# Consuming large JSON file with Apache Camel

Tags: file, apache-camel, jsonpath

I am trying to consume large JSON file with records in form of JSON Array using apache camel. I am using split() with jsonpath("$") to split the records which returns Map and works fine with small files. But for large files, it is loading everything in memory and causing outofmemoryerror.

Here is the code. Any suggestions how to handle large files?

```
from("file://{{data.file.inbound}}?charset=utf-8&readLock=changed&move={{data.file.processed}}&moveFailed={{data.file.failed}}")
                .id("file-to-mongodb").split().jsonpath("$").streaming()
                .to("log:com.manoj.oneByone");
```

Comment: You should use streams to load files in parts

Comment: I am surprised that you have memory problems since you already use the `.streaming()` in your route. I do the same for CSV files and it works very good with big files. Is it possible that the `jsonpath` expression enforces the complete file loading?

Comment: Yes, jsonpath loads all records in memory as a Map and that is causing all the issues.

Answer (score 1):

OOM has an issue due to loading whole file into memory.

I would try the below code, which copies the file in chunks:

```
from("file://{{data.file.inbound}}?charset=utf-8&readLock=changed&move={{data.file.processed}}&moveFailed={{data.file.failed}}")
                .id("file-to-mongodb").split().jsonpath("$").streaming()
                .to("log:com.manoj.oneByone?fileExist=Append");
```